# How do I import Libcurl to my C++ code?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I'm kinda new to programming, and I need to know how to use LibCurl in my C++ code. I'm told I need to use its libraries but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Besides, there are so many download options on the website that I don't really know which one to choose. I chose an executable that just gave me a .dll file and a .exe file.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Normally like this :

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

And `-lcurl`to compile

Comment: thank you, but i need more help on this. let me get this ryt..  i should add that #include line in the code, i get that. Then I type the -lcurl command where exactly? Thing is, I'm using this c++ scientific tool called ROOT and I just type .x <filename.C> to run that macro.

Comment: Basic compile command : `g++ -Wall -lcurl myFile.c`
Documentation : http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/